# angularjs ionic detect which view user came from

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

i am using ionic framework which uses the uiRouter.

In my code i am going from two different views to a single view and i want to do different actions base on where the user came from.

The common landing view is "result"
currently my result state is set up as such

```
    .state('tab.result', {
  url: '/result',
  params: {
    value1: null,
    value2:null,
    value3:null
  },
  views: {
    'tab-home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home-result.html',
      controller: 'resultCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

i have two paths from different view

1)

```
 $state.go("tab.result",{ 'value1':somevalue,'value1':somevalue,'value1':somevalue});
```

and in another view i am linking to it like so:

2)

```
 <ion-item ui-sref="tab.result">result</ion-item>
```

how do i setup my controller in my result view so i know where the user came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just remember previous state in $rootState ?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    $rootScope.previousState = fromState;
    $rootScope.previousParams = fromParams;
})
```